# How can you calculate the more beneficial stat increase between flat damage and % crit?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

In Divinity Original Sin 2 I can increase my stats when I level up.

1 point in Wits gives me +1% crit, 1 point in Finesse gives me +5% flat damage.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around the math needed to figure out which one would be more beneficial on average.

Is there a math formula where I could, with the crit chance increase of a point, the crit damage bonus and the flat damage increase of a point, which one is more beneficial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a problem for which Math ™ is the answer!

In general, the formula is going to look something like this:

```
D = Damage / hit.
C = Crit Chance
M = Crit Multiplier
```

Assuming 100% chance to hit, you'd get a base formula something like:

```
D * (1 - C) + D*M*(C) = Average Damage / Hit
```

But you're not interested in that, you're interested in the *change* in damage / hit. So from the above, we can derive the following:

```
F = Bonus Flat Damage Multiplier Addition
C' = Crit Chance Addition
```

Flat Damage Bonus

```
(1+F)*(D*(1-C) + D*M*(C))
```

Increasing Crit Chance Bonus

```
 D*(1-(C+C')) + D*M*(C+C')
```

Now that we have these two formulas, we'll need to use your actual numbers. But the important thing to realize, is that D, C, and M are constant, and when F and C' are 0, the two formulae are identical.

To make things simple, let's say you deal 100 damage per hit, your crit chance is 0%, and the crit multiplier is 2 (i.e., crits deal double damage) Slotting that into the above, we get these:

```
Avg Damage = (1+F)*(100*(1) + 100*2*0)
```

or in simpler terms:

```
Avg Damage = 100+100F
```

So in your 5% increase, Average Damage would be 100 + .05*100, or 105 damage.

Likewise:

```
Avg Damage = 100*(1-(0+C')) + 100 * 2 * (0+C')
Avg Damage = 100 - 100C' + 200 * C'
Avg Damage = 100 + 100C'
```

So in your 1% increase, Average damage would be 100 + .01*100 or 101 damage.

So pretty clearly, 5% increase in overall damage beats 1% increase in crit chance. That said, the actual formula used in Divinity: Original Sin is likely to be more complicated than that (i.e. taking elemental or crit damage % bonuses into effect).

So on the face, 1 point in Finesse gives you more damage. But Wisdom has other benefits (such as initiative) which vastly balloon out the problem space. The other wrinkle is that the base critical multiplier in the game is not 2, but variable (starting at 1.5 before other bonuses), but as you might notice from the example above, you'd need a multiplier of 5 before crit chance pulls ahead, which does not seem feasibly reachable.

Comment: Yeah in my playthrough with friends we decided to screw initiative because, of what we've seen, initiative is mostly against your own team. In a 4v4 fight, whatever is the initiative, the game will do one ally, then an enemy then back to an ally. So the only bonus in high initiative is going first and not second (and going first within your team.) So I might just respec in dropping my Wits for finesse. Go last, but hit like a truck.